# pass counter to anonymous function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Kindof a basic question, but how do I pass a distinct value to an anonymous function?

Maybe there's a better way of phrasing this... what I mean is, consider the following code... assuming I have a bunch of clickable items with ids like somediv1, somediv2, etc.

```
for(idx = 1; idx < 30; idx++) {
    $("#somediv" + idx).on('click', function() {foo(idx); });
}

function foo(inIDX) {
    alert(inIDX);
}
```

No matter which div I click, it always alerts 30. I'd like clicking somediv1 to alert 1, somediv2 to alert 2, and so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the callback is called `idx` has the value of end of loop.

Here's a standard solution :

```
for(idx = 1; idx < 30; idx++) {
   (function(i){
    $("#somediv" + idx).on('click', function() {foo(i); });
   })(idx);
}
```

The intermediate function, which is called immediately, stores the value of `idx` at time of execution of the loop.

Maybe I could make it clearer by remembering that in JavaScript

- the scope of a variable is either a function or the global scope (never a simple block)
- a function keeps a pointer to the scope in which it was declared and can use the variables of this scope when it's executed (this is called a closure)

Comment: Interesting, would `for (i=1; i<x; i++) { var j=i; function() {foo(j);} }` work?

Comment: @dualed your test doesn't pass the callback, so I'm not sure of what you mean but declaring a variable inside the block isn't enough : the scope of a variable isn't a block but a function (or the global scope).

Comment: this works, will have to crack my teeth to understand why (coming to Javascript from mainly Actionscript...)

This is great, any pointers to pages which explain this concept would be fantastic

Comment: @dystroy meh, its hard to check the code without preview :( But yes, that is exactly what I meant to ask

Comment: @davidkomer [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) and [another one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures). Understanding this code is very important to get what happens in most JavaScript programs.